# Transactional Email using Mailgun Email Template and Dynamic content Apart

Tags: php, mailgun, email

[image: Mailgun Email Template]

I have successfully setup a Mailgun account for Transaction email.

The Problem;

I want my email content which are dynamic inside my Email Template please help and even my file attachment not working

```
<?php
$filePath='@/home/allinclende/public_html/apply/CIW.pdf';
$message = $message;
$html  = file_get_contents('email_1.html');
$html .= $message;

$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
//enter domain which you find in Default Password 
$domain = "apply.allinc.com";

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
'from' => 'Jane Doe <jdoe@allinc.com>',
 'to' => $add,
 'cc' => 'inquiry <info@allinc.com>',
 'subject' => $subject,
 'text' => $message,
 'html' => $html,
 'attachment[1]' => $filePath
)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your email_1.html file include some unique placeholders. Make an array containing them:

```
$search = array("FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME", "APPOINTMENTDATE");
```

Query your database and get the variables to replace each one, make an array of those:

```
$replace = array($firstname, $lastname, $appointmentdate);
```

Then it's as simple as:

```
$customhtml = str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
```

Send `$customhtml` via mailgun, then loop through again to personalise the email for each customer

Correct construct for sending an attachment is like this:

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
'from' => 'Jane Doe <jdoe@allinc.com>',
 'to' => $add,
 'cc' => 'inquiry <info@allinc.com>',
 'subject' => $subject,
 'text' => $message,
 'html' => $html
), array(
    'attachment' => array('@/home/allinclende/public_html/apply/CIW.pdf')
));
```

Comment: And my attachement never get sent?

Comment: Your syntax is bad. I've added the correct syntax to my answer

Comment: Solved but one thing to check out guys is this Important: You must use multipart/form-data encoding when sending attachments.